# First push notification disappears after few seconds

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My app first `notification` disappears after few seconds itself when app is in `background` even when the user has not taken any action to that `notification`. After that every `notification` remains in place.

Does setting application `badge number` to 0 or cancelling `local` `notifications` has any effect on this.(I tried commenting those parts but it did not fix).

```
`func application(application: UIApplication, 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) 
 -> Bool {


    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])

    registerForPushNotifications(application)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    //Firebase push notification
    FIRApp.configure()



    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification),
                                                    name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification,
                                                    object: nil)

  UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0



    }


}`

  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    guard  let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject] else{
        return
    }

    let state = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState
    if state == .Background || state == .Inactive{
       //do some background work
   }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: Does the 2nd notification have buttons and the 1st one doesn't have buttons ?

Comment: Just remove setting applicationBadgeNumber and try once.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is due to manually setting the badge number. I had code in my app to manually set the badge number on application launch (either to 0 or to a value saved in NSUserDefaults, depending on the situation) and found that doing either one of these would cause the notification banner to disappear and the sound would cut off mid-notification. To solve it, I checked the `applicationState` and if it was `UIApplicationStateBackground` I did not touch the badge number.

So, based on your code above, either remove the line in `didFinishLaunching` to set the badge to 0, or ensure the application state is not background before setting to 0.

I posted a similar answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53381819/2788608

Comment: as you mentioned above only single line fixed the issue 
`if application.applicationState != .background {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        }`